# Windows 10 Home : generic licence

Tags: windows-10

On 2 unrelated computers when I extract Windows 10 Home key using **Belarc** Advisor I got the exact same key. I searched for this key on Google **(YTMG3-N6DKC-DKB77-7M9GH-8HVX7)** and it looks like it is a **"generic" license**. Both computers have been upgraded to Windows 10 and have their original license in the ACPI table.

What is those generic licenses and are they really valid?

Comment: If you go to activation in settings does it say activated with digital entitlement?

Comment: After upgrade, your license and activation is stored in the Microsoft Licensing Server (not BIOS) and so long as Windows has been activated on these two computers, you do not need the key above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Both PC has been upgrade to Windows 10 and have their original licence in the BIOS.

Due to the fact you upgraded to Windows 10 from a previous version of Windows, you do not have a Windows 10 license, but the license key that Belarc Advisor is detecting is the correct key.

Any eligible Windows installation that was upgraded to Windows 10 Home will have one key.  Eligible Windows installations that were upgraded to Windows 10 Professional will have a different generic license key.  Windows installations that were upgraded to Windows 10 from a previous version of Windows have a digital entitelement.  **It is expected behavior to have one of the following generic keys if you upgraded from a previous version of Windows.**

- Windows 10 Home: YTMG3-N6DKC-DKB77-7M9GH-8HVX7
- Windows 10 Professional: VK7JG-NPHTM-C97JM-9MPGT-3V66T

Source: [Activate Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12440/windows-10-activate)

> What is those generic licence and are they really valid?

Due to the fact you upgraded a previous version of Windows to Windows 10.  You do not have a Windows 10 license key, since a license key is required in order to activate your installation, Microsoft uses a generic key depending on which edition of Windows 10 you upgraded to.  **The license you are detecting is valid.**

Source: [Whats up with the generic keys?](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3f0st5/whats_up_with_the_generic_keys/)